# C++ - Declaration of method incompatible

Tags: c++, visual-c++

EDIT:

- I'm using namespace std
- I'm using VS10
- Room is a separate class
- I've included the memory header in all necessary files

The original error was an Intellisense error I was getting before building. After building, I got a buttload more:

---

- [The original Intellisense error before building] declaration is incompatible with "std::tr1::shared_ptr<< error-type >> Option::getRoom()
- 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty> Option::getRoom(void)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'std::tr1::shared_ptr Option::getRoom(void)'
- 'Option::getRoom' : redefinition; different basic types
- 'Option::getRoom' uses undefined class 'std::tr1::shared_ptr'

These are related to this piece of code in Option.cpp:

```
shared_ptr<Room> Option::getRoom(){
    shared_ptr<Room> room(new Room);
    return room;
}
```

The corresponding code in Option.hpp:

```
public:
  virtual shared_ptr<Room> getRoom();
```

---

- Error 'RoomOption::getRoom': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'Option::getRoom'
- [IntelliSense] return type is not identical to nor covariant with return type "std::tr1::shared_ptr<< error-type >>" of overridden virtual function function "Option::getRoom"

This is related to this piece of code in RoomOption.hpp, a subclass of Option:

```
public:
shared_ptr<Room> getRoom();
```

---

Here's all the code from the two classes I'm having trouble with:

Option.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Room.h"
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Option
{
protected:
    int id;
    char* text;
public:
    Option(void);
    Option(int, char*);
    virtual ~Option(void);
    char* getText();
    int getID();
    virtual shared_ptr<Room> getRoom();
};
```

Option.cpp:

```
#include "Option.h"
#include "Room.h"
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

Option::Option(void)
{
}

Option::Option(int newID, char* newText){
    id = newID;
    text = newText;
}

Option::~Option(void)
{
}

char* Option::getText(){
    return text;
}

int Option::getID(){
    return id;
}

shared_ptr<Room> Option::getRoom(){
    shared_ptr<Room> room(new Room());
    return room;
    //note that this function will never be used. I'd prefer to
    //pass back a null pointer but I couldn't do that either.
}
```

RoomOption.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Option.h"
#include "Room.h"
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class RoomOption :
    public Option
{
private:
    shared_ptr<Room> room;
public:
    RoomOption(void);
    RoomOption(int, char*, shared_ptr<Room>);
    ~RoomOption(void);
    void setRoom(shared_ptr<Room>);
    shared_ptr<Room> getRoom();
};
```

RoomOption.cpp:

```
#include "RoomOption.h"
#include "Room.h"
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

RoomOption::RoomOption(void)
{
}

RoomOption::RoomOption(int newID, char* newText, shared_ptr<Room> newRoom)
{
    id = newID;
    strcpy(text, newText);
    room = newRoom;
}

RoomOption::~RoomOption(void)
{
}

void RoomOption::setRoom(shared_ptr<Room> newRoom){
    room = newRoom;
}

shared_ptr<Room> RoomOption::getRoom(){
    return room;
}
```

Comment: Do you have `using namespace std;` or other `using` declarations anywhere?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem, could you post a complete sample which reproduces the problem? Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: Is the `Room` type declared inside your `Option` class?? Then you need to write `shared_ptr<Option::Room> as return type in your .cpp file.

Comment: Are you actually getting an error when _building_, or is this merely an (ignorable) IntelliSense error?

Comment: Why does the message say `error-type`?  Is `Room` a class, struct, typedef, or template parameter?

Comment: @Jean : We need to see the contents of Room.h too...

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles without error at /W4 /WX with VS 2010:

```
#include <memory>

struct Room {};

class Option {
  public:
    std::shared_ptr<Room> getRoom();
};

std::shared_ptr<Room> Option::getRoom(){
    std::shared_ptr<Room> room(new Room());
    return room;
}

int main() {
  Option opt;
  std::shared_ptr<Room> room = opt.getRoom();
  return 0;
}
```

What are you doing differently?

Answer (score -1):

Is `Room` declared at the point where it's used in the `getRoom()` call in Option.hpp?

Have you tried removing the `()` from `new Room()` in case you're somehow getting hit by the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), possibly in other code we can't see??